# Including metadata on QGIS 3 models?

Tags: qgis, metadata, qgis-modeler

Models on QGIS 3 are stored following a XML schema. Do you know if it is possible to embed metadata, may be using Dulin Core or ISO? I have noted that the modeler's help take in account subjects like: author, version, documentation and so on. But I am not sure how to include metadata information on .model3 files.

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% on this but I think metadata is a work in progress, being approached from a number of angles.

If you have metadata to save, apparently it can be saved to a file which sits in the same directory as the data. As per this answer QGIS Default Metadata

If you are trying to read existing metadata from another system (your case) I presume QGIS is expecting to read a *.qmd file.

There is a plugin which apparently used to help some users, but apparently it no longer works with updated version of QGIS. https://github.com/nextgis/metatools/issues

Comment: Please do not provide the same answer to multiple questions. If it truly applies to more than one question then those questions are probably duplicates and should be flagged as such.